# How to restrict submit handler when ajax button is clicked in altered form

Tags: forms, ajax, ubercart

I am altering ubercart "uc_product_add_to_cart_form" and adding an ajax button "calculate price":

```
  $form['price_calculation']['calculate'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => t('Prepočítať'),
      '#ajax' => array(
          'callback' => 'activit_calculate_price_ajax',
          'wrapper' => 'price-calculation-value',
          'effect' => 'fade',
          'method' => 'replace'
      ),
  );
```

This button is just replacing some text info about price based on filled attributes.

**Problem is** that it also calls submit handler and it adds product to cart.

In case of my own custom submit handler I could verify what button is triggering submit handler, something like `if ($form_state['triggering_element']['#value'] == 'calculate') {}`. But this is not a custom submit handler. It is default submit handler of altered ubercart form.

Is there any other way to prevent submit handler when ajax button is clicked?

---

**UDATE** - I explored ubercart submit handler and commented all the code and added dsm($form_state);

```
function uc_product_add_to_cart_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  dsm($form_state);
  /*
  $form_state['redirect'] =

      uc_cart_add_item(
          $form_state['values']['nid'],
          $form_state['values']['qty'],
          module_invoke_all(
              'uc_add_to_cart_data',
              $form_state['values']
          ),
          NULL,
          variable_get('uc_cart_add_item_msg', TRUE)
      );
  */
}
```

Weird thing is that $form state shows that triggering element is 'add-to-cart' even if I click only 'calculate price' button.

Comment: Form API has [`#executes_submit_callback`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x#executes_submit_callback) I haven't used it though, just remembered seeing it.

Comment: Looks like good tip, but it does nothing, submit handler is being still triggered

Comment: Did you try to make the calculate button a submit `#type` and your submit to something like `'#submit' => array('your_submit_function')`. This _should_ override the default submit functions and allow you to do your price calculations and return them in `$form_state`.

Comment: I have tried '#submit' => array(''), but no success.

Comment: What's your ajax callback look like?